# Mysql performance with a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

i have a table of resumes - names, resume text, zipcode, firstname, lastname, longitude, latitude, zip ... 500,000+ rows

i query it too ways:

by location, example:

```
1) SELECT * FROM resumes 
WHERE ((latitude BETWEEN 44.3523845787 AND 45.6809474213) 
AND (longitude BETWEEN -110.873064254 AND -108.993603746)) 
GROUP BY lastname,longitude 
LIMIT 0, 50 
by name

2) SELECT * from resumes 
   (MATCH(resume) AGAINST ('donald')) AS relevance 
    FROM resumes 
    WHERE (MATCH(resume) AGAINST ('donald')) 
    GROUP BY lastname,longitude 
    ORDER BY relevance DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 50
```

queries on this table are very slow at first, but same query afterwards is faster, i think it's caching it ...

how can i speed up these queries? thanks

Comment: Quick/dirty tip: Any field used in a `where` or `join` or `group by` clause should have an index on it.

Comment: did you add indexes on latitude, longitude, lastname, and resume? (i.e., what other marc just said while i as typing this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) SELECT * FROM resumes 
WHERE ((latitude BETWEEN 44.3523845787 AND 45.6809474213) 
AND (longitude BETWEEN -110.873064254 AND -108.993603746)) 
GROUP BY lastname,longitude 
LIMIT 0, 50 
by name
```

This one can make little use of btree indexes. At best, it would grab all locations that fit for the latitude, or the longitude, and investigate potential rows along the other dimension. What you want is for it to only investigate rows that fit in a smaller box.

For this, you need a [spacial index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html).

```
2) SELECT * from resumes 
   (MATCH(resume) AGAINST ('donald')) AS relevance 
    FROM resumes 
    WHERE (MATCH(resume) AGAINST ('donald')) 
    GROUP BY lastname,longitude 
    ORDER BY relevance DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 50
```

Likewise, this also needs a special kind of index which is not btree -- a [full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) to be specific.

Comment: SELECT firstname, lastname,dateadded,zip,resume_id FROM resumes WHERE ((latitude BETWEEN 34.3861330183 AND 35.7139349817) AND (longitude BETWEEN -87.9631695654 AND -86.3412124346)) LIMIT 0, 50

Comment: after trying "alter table resumes add spatial index (latitude)" i get error #1089 - Incorrect sub part key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique sub keys

Comment: make sure your table is using the [myisam engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). then: `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX resumes_sp_index ON resumes (latitude, longitude);` and `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX resumes_ft_index ON resumes (resume);`.

Comment: the issue is that my longitude and latitude are stored as float right now, and i think i need to convert them to spatial field type. do you have any advice on which spatial field type i should use (geometry, point,etc) and how i would go about doing it? thanks so much

Comment: A point seems right, but it might be a box that you need for it to get indexed... (In Postgres, I'd use a box outright, since that's what it ends up being in the index anyway.) As mysql won't allow to index an expression last I checked, you might want to investigate populating it using triggers, too.

Comment: so i go to phpmyadmin, table structure, select latitude field and then change type from float to spatial point. but all the latitude fields instead of like 74.28282732 become [GEOMETRY - 0B] ... what am i doing wrong? thanks

Comment: To be very frank, I've never actually used MySQL's spatial indexes. I've played around with [Postgis](http://postgis.refractions.net/) and Postgre's [geometry types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-geometric.html)... Which have similarities, but for all intents and purposes you're reaching the limits of what I know about MySQL... In Postgres, you'd want to add an expression index using gist on a point based on the latitude and longitude. So in MySQL, you probably want to add an extra column that contains the point, and index that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use indexes on all fields used to join tables.
2. Use indexes on the fields that you use in your where clause.
3. Don't use 'select *' select **only the fields that you need**.
4. Group by sorts your resultset on the grouped fields, if you an order by on a different field *(or a different order)* you are forcing an extra sort slowing things down.
5. MySQL does shortcut evaluation put the condition that limits the maximum number of rows first in your where clause.
6. Select * with a group by is a different way of writing "eliminate duplicate rows" if you lay out your tables so there are no duplicate rows to begin with you don't need the group by either. This will speed up your queries a lot.
7. Specify your lat and longitude field as type point and put a spatial index on those. I'd give you a link but I'm on the iphone now so that's a bit of a hassle now.

Comment: Re point 1 and 2, Btree indexes won't help here. He needs spacial indexes, short of scanning huge chunks of the table.